# how to conditionally only show items based upon a status in a vue list

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following Vue codem (here's a fiddle) https://jsfiddle.net/he26tn53/:

```
<div id="app"></div>

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  template:`<h2>People:</h2><span @click="showOnlyEnabled = !showOnlyEnable"> toggle enabled</span>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="person in people">
      <label>
        <span>
          {{ person.name }}
        </span>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ol>`,

  data: {
    showOnlyEnabled: false, 
    people: [
      { name: "Joe", isEnabled: false },
      { name: "Jonie", isEnabled: false },
      { name: "Jill", isEnabled: true },    
      { name: "Jack", isEnabled: true },    
      ]
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(todo){
        todo.done = !todo.done
    }
  }
})
```

and would like the toggle enabled to force only enabled users to be shown. I'd rather not have to do two checks like:

```
<span v-if="showOnlyEnabled">
   <template v-if="person.isEnabled">
      {{person.name}}
   </template>
</span>
<span v-else>
      {{person.name}}
</span>
```

Is there a more concise way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-v-if, you can use both `v-for` and `v-if` on the same element.

You just need to right Boolean expression

```
<li v-for="person in people" v-if="person.isEnabled || !showOnlyEnabled">
```

---

Alternately, use a computed property and a filter (with the same logic as above)

```
computed: {
  filteredPeople() {
    return this.people.filter(({isEnabled}) => isEnabled || !showOnlyEnabled)
  }
}
```

and

```
<li v-for="person in filteredPeople">
```

Comment: ah, I literally had to speak out the logic to see what was going on. thx

Comment: @timpone so did I. It's the logical inversions (ie `!`) that tax my brain